# Website is different when I upload on FTP

Tags: caching, web

I have just started developing for a few weeks now and I bought a domain, but when I upload the files on live, the website looks different than what I have uploaded. Now, this gets fixed when I clear my cache. The problem is that my visitors enter, they see the page in a way, and after I update it they see it as the previous version!
Is there any possible solution for this? I don't want my visitors to clear cache every time I make a change on my website!

Comment: You should add more information, if you want to get concrete help. Tell us more about the programming language/admin system you use for the website - get more technical.

Comment: html + css + bootstrap, from what I saw my CSS doesn't get updated correctly unless I clear the cache.....

Answer (score 2):

This is quite probable to be due to css cache. Your server is loading a cached version. You can specify the cached time in a few ways. Etags and htaccess (on apache) are the most common.

A very simple trick is just to add at the end of your style link url (where you load your main style in the head of the document) a get-like parameter: just like this:

`main.css?v=2`

Comment: `Your server is loading a cached version` correction, the client browser is caching not the server..